# 1 hour Session high and Low

Tags: pine-script, stock, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I want to see the first hours high and low and have it marked on my chart on the 5 minute timeframe

The issue I'm having it that the lines from the previous days hour high/low are going into the current session until the new current session high/low is drawn.

How and I plot the current days high/low up during the first hour and then plot have that plotted for the rest of the day?

Below is my code:

```
bartimeSess = time('D')
newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]


high_range = ta.valuewhen(newbarSess,high,0) 
low_range = ta.valuewhen(newbarSess,low,0)

locHigh = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", high_range)
locLow = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", low_range)

up1= plot(time(timeframe.period) > 0 ? locHigh : na,title="IB High", color=color.lime, 
transp=20, linewidth=2)
down1 = plot(time(timeframe.period) > 0 ? locLow : na,title="IB Low", color=color.red, 
transp=20, linewidth=2)

fill(up1, down1, color = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 83))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//@version=4   
showInitialBalance = input(true,title="Initial Balance")  
//Session Rules    
bartimeSess = time("D")
newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]
high_range = valuewhen(newbarSess,high,0)
low_range = valuewhen(newbarSess,low,0)
adopt(r, s) => security(syminfo.tickerid, r, s,lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

//Formula For Opening Range  
highRes = adopt(res, high_range)  
lowRes = adopt(res, low_range)

//Plot Statements For Opening Range Lines  
p1 = plot(showAll and showInitialBalance and highRes ? highRes : na, color=color.aqua, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)  

p2 = plot(showAll and showInitialBalance and lowRes ? lowRes : na, color=color.aqua, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=2)  

sixtyMinHigh = showAll and showInitialBalance and highRes ? label.new(bar_index, highRes, text=display_value ? ("                        1HrH"  + " " + tostring(nround(highRes))) : "1h-High",  style= label.style_none,size= size.normal) : na  

label.set_textcolor(sixtyMinHigh,textcolor=color.aqua)  
label.delete(sixtyMinHigh[1])  

sixtyMinLow = showAll and showInitialBalance and lowRes ? label.new(bar_index, lowRes, text=display_value ? ("                        1HrL"  + " " + tostring(nround(lowRes))) : "1h-Low",  style= label.style_none, size= size.normal) : na  

label.set_textcolor(sixtyMinLow,textcolor=color.aqua)  
label.delete(sixtyMinLow[1])  

fill(p1, p2, color=color.aqua, transp=95)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?